# how to check if the user has rated a review?

Tags: php, html, mysql, symfony, rating-system

I am currently developing a book review system using 5 star rating. I want to add a rating system to each review a user post. therefore I have created a table to store each rate and the bookId that been currently rated, as well as the id, review and the userId who have posted as follow:

```
id  Review  rating  AppUser_id  Book_id
46  reviw1  2           6          23
53  reviw2  3           6         23
```

the following are the html for the stars:

```
    {% if UserId >0 %}
    <form class="form-signin" action="/BookReview{% if ReviewId != -1 %}/{{ ReviewId }}{% endif %}/{{ act }}" method="POST">

        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please Post Your Review</h2>
        <label for="Review" class="sr-only">Review</label>

        <textarea name="review" id="Review" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Review Here" required autofocus>{{ review }}</textarea>

        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" >Submit</button>
        <fieldset class="rating">
            <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating5" value="5" /><label for="star5" title="Rocks!">5 stars</label>
            <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating4" value="4" /><label for="star4" title="Pretty good">4 stars</label>
            <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating3" value="3" /><label for="star3" title="Meh">3 stars</label>
            <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating2" value="2" /><label for="star2" title="Kinda bad">2 stars</label>
            <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating1" value="1" /><label for="star1" title="Sucks big time">1 star</label>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    {% endif %}
```

the following is the controller:

```
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST' and $act == -1) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $review = $request->request->get('review');
        $review = $request->request->get('BookId');
        $rate1 = $request->request->get('rating1');
        $rate2 = $request->request->get('rating2');
        $rate3 = $request->request->get('rating3');
        $rate4 = $request->request->get('rating4');
        $rate5 = $request->request->get('rating5');


        $br = new BookReview();
        $br->setReview($review);
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:AppUser');
        $User = $repository->findOneBy(array('id' => $userId));
        $br->setAppUser($User);
        $br->setBook($book);


            if($rate1)
            {
                $br->setRating(1);

            }elseif($rate2)
            {
                $br->setRating(2);
            }elseif($rate3)
            {
                $br->setRating(3);
            }elseif($rate4)
            {
                $br->setRating(4);
            }elseif($rate5)
            {
                $br->setRating(5);
            }


        $em->persist($br);
        $em->flush();
        $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Review Added');

        return array('book' => $book, 'reviews' => $book->getBookReviews(), 'Title' => '', 'Message' => '', 'id' => $userId, 'review' => '', 'ReviewId' => $ReviewId, 'act' => $act);
    }
```

here is my question, how can I check if the user has rated the same book before, and if he has rated the book before then set the rate using this part of code which where fully provided on the above controller:

```
if($rate1)
                {
                    $br->setRating(1);

                }elseif($rate2)
                {
                    $br->setRating(2);
                }elseif($rate3)
                {
                    $br->setRating(3);
                }elseif($rate4)
                {
                    $br->setRating(4);
                }elseif($rate5)
                {
                    $br->setRating(5);
                }
```

the second question is how to for calculate the over-all average rating of the book. I am using symfony2(PHP)

the following are my attempt which is not seems to be working:

```
        $br = new BookReview();

        $br->setReview($review);
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:AppUser');
        $User = $repository->findOneBy(array('id' => $userId));
        $br->setAppUser($User);
        $br->setBook($book);
        $book_id = $br->getBook(); $request->request->get('book_id');
        $user_id = $br->getAppUser(); $request->request->get('user_id');
        $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT br FROM AppBundle:BookReview br WHERE (br.Book = ' . $book_id . ' and br.AppUser = ' . $user_id . ')');

        $results = $query->getResult();



        if ($results){
            $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'no Added');

        }


        else{

            if($rate1)
            {
                $br->setRating(1);

            }elseif($rate2)
            {
                $br->setRating(2);
            }elseif($rate3)
            {
                $br->setRating(3);
            }elseif($rate4)
            {
                $br->setRating(4);
            }elseif($rate5)
            {
                $br->setRating(5);
            }
        }
```

Comment: in your `rating` field, `2   6` what mean of this?

Comment: I will edit it just a mistake

Answer (score 1):

First of all your controller and view look a bit messy. What for do you need different names for rating fields? It't radio buttons. Just set the same name for all of your radio buttons. Then you will not need if-else condition to determine which rating value has been chosen.

To get know if a user has already reviewed some book you need to know if there is entry with such user_id and such book_id. This retrieving doesn't require to return an object in result and it's much easier to execute simple sql to get number of rows with appropriate values. You can do it using database_connection service from your controller:

```
$this->get('database_connection')
     ->fetchColumn('select count(*) as cnt 
                    from book_reviews 
                    where user_id = ? and book_id = ?', array($userId, $bookId));
```

Or from repository:

```
public function userHasAlreadyReviewedBook($userId, $bookId)
{
    $connection = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
    $query = 'select count(*) as cnt 
              from book_reviews 
              where user_id = ? and book_id = ?';

    return $connection->fetchColumn($query, array($userId, $bookId)) > 0;
}
```

Or you can specify a special service for such actions and inject 'database_connection' into it.

If the request above will return something more than zero then the user has already reviewed the book.

To get average value of book reviews rating you can again use the database_connection service (of course if you don't need to have this value in some complex set of data):

For each book in reviews:

```
$connection->fetchAll('select avg(rating) as average_rating 
                       from book_reviews 
                       group by book_id');
```

or for some special book:

```
$connection->fetchColumn('select avg(rating) as average_rating 
                          from book_reviews 
                          where book_id = ?', array($bookId));
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

In your repository, you can add this :

```
public function getCurrentRated($bookId, $userId)
{
$sql = 'SELECT avg(rating) as totalRated FROM your_table WHERE AppUser_id = :userId and Book_id = :bookId group by Book_id';
$params = array(
    'userId' => $userId,
    'bookId' => $bookId,
);

return $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->executeQuery($sql, $params)->fetchAll();
}
```

And then call it in your controller like this :

```
$currentRated = $repository->getCurrentRated($bookId, $userId);
```

Comment: Why do you suggest divide rating sum to rating count? There is avg function in mysql.

Comment: @Alex : Thank you, I just know it :'(

Answer (score 0):

First I will strongly suggest you to give to all your radio inputs a name of `rating` (not `rating1`, `rating2`, ...). This way you will know what rating the user gave to the book by getting the value of `$request->request->get('rating')`.

Now how to check if the user already rated that book? Use this query:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:BookReview');
$bookReview = $repository->findOneBy(array('AppUser_id' => $userId, 'Book_id' => $bookId));

if (!$bookReview) {
    $bookReview = new BookReview();
    $bookReview->setUser($user);
    $bookReview->setBook($book);
    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist();
}

$bookReview->setRating($request->request->get('rating'));

$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
```